# Weird back button (Alt-Left) behavior in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, ide, navigation

*Not exactly a programming question, but I figured I'd get more response here than in SU. Tag 'java' added because I'm programming in Java. Feel free to edit/move question as appropriate.*

I'm using **Eclipse Kepler IDE**, and I'm having this annoying weird behavior from the **Back** function. I can't remember if I had this behavior in *Juno* version but I think not - that's what I'm here to confirm, if this is a bug *or* I need to adjust some setting in *Eclipse*.

Imagine the following code points:

- Point A
- Point B
- Point C

When my editing cursor is at point A and I hit <kbd>F3</kbd> (*Open Declaration*), Eclipse takes me to B. If I hit <kbd>F3</kbd> again, Eclipse takes me to C.

All that is well, but when I hit the **Back** button or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> from C, I'm being taken back to A. If I then hit **Forward** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>), I'm taken to B and the **Forward** button is disabled! (I can't go forward to C).

```
Current Behavior:
F3:      A -> B -> C
Back:    C ------> A
Forward: A -> B
```

This doesn't seem right at all, because I would expect going back from C, I should reach B, and then to A. Following that, going forward from A, I should go to B, and then to C.

```
Expected Behavior:
F3:      A -> B -> C
Back:    C -> B -> A
Forward: A -> B -> C
```

Comment: Works fine for me in kepler.

Comment: I think I'm seeing this wrong. Is it supposed to go to point where traversal to C was invoked, but not traverse till C when I hit _forward_? Seems an odd design choice...

Comment: I am seeing this as well in Kepler. After a fresh start all seems to be working as it should but after use for some time I need to Alt->Left Alt->Right to go back as stated above. I've not quite figured out the sequence of events which causes this to happen.

Comment: I have this too, and it is very disrupting. It seems Eclipse often "forgets" to add the current file to the navigation history. Eclipse has been deteriorating, this and other disruptive issues - Indigo was the last good version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your eclipse. They fixed this bug in the last days. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing this as well seems to be new to Kepler and also present in Luna builds

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the guys from eclipse are already working on this.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413474

Comment: Although I didn't have to switch perspectives.

Comment: See the link in the answer of user2755510 - it also happens if you newly open a closed file with "open declaration". Although the bug is found in Kepler SR1 and will be fixed in 4.4 M2 if I understood it right.

Answer (score 1):

I Think that this has already been fixed, see

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417001

The fix is also available in Kepler SR1.